# Python asyncio: Future vs Task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This creates a `future`

```
loop.run_in_executor(None, some_fn)
```

This creates a `task`

```
asyncio.create_task(some_fn())
```

**What is the difference between the two?**

According to my understanding:

The former spins up **another** thread and executes the function (which is typically IO-bound) concurrently.

The latter creates a task within the **same thread** and executes the function concurrently.

Is this correct? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) isn't really helpful in understanding the differences between the two.

Answer (score 33):

> What is the difference between [futures and tasks]?

In short, future is the more general concept of a container of an async result, akin to a JavaScript promise. Task is a subclass of future specialized for executing coroutines.

Nothing in the definition of asyncio future indicates multi-threaded execution, and asyncio is in fact strongly single-threaded. It's a specific feature of `run_in_executor` that it safely synchronizes functions it invokes in other threads with an asyncio future it creates and returns.

Also, be careful not to confuse [asyncio futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html) with [concurrent.futures futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future), the latter being indeed multi-threaded. Despite similarities in the API coming from the fact that asyncio futures were inspired by the ones from `concurrent.futures`, they work in conceptually different ways and cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: what are other subclasses of futures except Tasks? it other word, what other job can be done by a future that is not ''executing of coroutines"?

Comment: @garej An ordinary future is useful to connect callbacks, like JS promises. In particular it serves as bridge between callbacks and coroutines. You can create a future and pass it to a callback which will later invoke `fut.set_result(x)`. A coroutine can `await` it in the meantime (or await several such futures with `gather()` etc.) When the callback completes the future, the coroutine that awaited it gets resumed and `await <future>` gets evaluated to the `x` the callback passed to `set_result()`. Asyncio plumbing code, the transports and protocols layer, is all written in this style.

Answer (score 11):

*My answers are assuming you use the default loops provided by Python based on your OS with CPython.

The [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task(some_fn)) method is used to schedule the execution of a coroutine (here `some_fn`) on the event loop. Since the event loop runs on a single thread, the coroutine will be executed asynchronously to the current context by using cooperative multitasking.

Contrary to that, [`loop.run_in_executor(None, some_fn)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), will use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create a thread pool, and perform the tasks, usually BlockingIO, with preemptive multitasking. You can see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L112) the implementation for `ThreadPoolExecutor` in CPython. In the implementation, you'll see that it creates a queue and a pool of threads which will get tasks from the queue and perform them. So yes - it will create a new thread for your scheduled task.

---

A couple of notes:

1. A `Task` is a `Future`
2. Generally speaking, if your code does not have blockingIO methods, and you can leverage asyncio for all your IOs, you will be better just using the event loop, without the need to use an `Executor` explicitly. This will be both more efficient since your code now uses cooperative multitasking, and will simplify execution since you know when your code gives back control to the event loop, thus managing concurrency (e.g. race condition) is either very simple or even non-existent.